# How to bring App in Foreground programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

I develop some LocalNotifications for my iOS8-App using `UIMutableUserNotificationAction`

In case of the App is running in background and the user touches at this `UIMutableUserNotificationAction` the app should be comeback to foreground.

**How can i solve that ?**

The event that `UIMutableUserNotificationAction` fires is:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString 
*)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate your storyboard and view controllers in application:handleWithIdentifier.. and push the view controller to the navigation controller if you have one or set as the root view controller if you don't have one.

You can also use `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method.

Something like this:

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
    {
            MyViewController *presenterVC = [_storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

            [_navigationController pushViewController:presenterVC animated:NO];    

            self.window.rootViewController = _navigationController;

    }
```

Comment: Did no work for me. I'm not using Storyboard.
`TabViewController *tabViewController = [TabViewController new];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabViewController;` and using `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` has also no effect.

Comment: No, only hardcoded stuff. I found a lot of posts where users said it's not possible (e.g. for a LocalNotification) to bring a App back to foreground programmatically -> It needs user-interactivity. But i'm using the new iOS8 _interactive notifications_ where the user interacts with. So i would say it should be possible... but how ?